# Nonnegative tensor decomposition example using Tensorly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorly

I am very new to **tensor** and also to **tensorly** Library.I come across one of the best examples of tensor decomposition on [jeankossaifi](http://jeankossaifi.com/blog/rpca.html) but I need an example of tensorly function non_negative_tucker() for tensor decomposition by extending the example on the link above (for Olivetti dataset).

Answer (score 1):

The interface is pretty much the same as the [robust_pca](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.robust_pca.html#tensorly.decomposition.robust_pca) one.

Let's create a random example tensor `X`,:

```
import tensorly as tl
import numpy as np

X = tl.tensor(np.random.random((10, 11, 12)))
```

You would apply robust tensor PCA as follows:

```
from tensorly.decomposition import robust_pca

D, E = robust_pca(X)
```

This gives you a low-rank tensor `D`, and a sparse one `E`, such that `D + E = X`  (approximately).

Instead, non-negative Tucker will return you a non-negative core and some non-negative factors. Note that now you have to specify a rank as well, for the decomposition.

```
from tensorly.decomposition import non_negative_tucker
core, factors = non_negative_tucker(X, rank=(12, 12, 12), n_iter_max=1000)
```

You can reconstruct the tensor using these and check the reconstruction error:

```
reconstruction = tl.tucker_to_tensor(core, factors)
error = tl.norm(reconstruction - X)/tl.norm(X)
```

You can have a look at the [API page](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.non_negative_tucker.html#tensorly.decomposition.non_negative_tucker) for that function.

Comment: here is the code:
`core, tucker_factors,rec_errors, mode = non_negative_tucker(X, rank=tucker_rank, n_iter_max=100, init='random')`


`tucker_reconstruction = tl.tucker_to_tensor(core, tucker_factors)`

`visualise_images(tucker_reconstruction, 12, 4)`

I am not getting the correct result in displaying the images.I have just extended the example of [jeankossaifi](http://jeankossaifi.com/blog/rpca.html) .

Comment: You are not using the function correctly: `non_negative_tucker` does not return reconstruction errors or mode.
The correct usage is the one I wrote in the post, e.g. `core, factors = non_negative_tucker(X, rank=(12, 12, 12), n_iter_max=1000)`.

Comment: i have changed the code accordingly,which looks like:
 `data = fetch_olivetti_faces()


X = data.images
X = X.astype(np.float64)


X -= X.mean()


tucker_rank = [80, 80, 80]


core, tucker_factors = non_negative_tucker(X, rank=tucker_rank, n_iter_max=100, init='random')


tucker_reconstruction = tl.tucker_to_tensor(core, tucker_factors)


visualise_images(tucker_reconstruction, 12, 4)`


The output is still a set of blurred images.
Please correct if there is anything wrong in the code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you need the factors and the core to be non-negative? If not, try Tucker (or partial_tucker if you don't need to factorise over the sample dimension). Also images are of size 64x64 but you chose a rank of 80 on these dimensions so you are over-parametrising. Finally, svd is a much better initialisation than random. So, with tucker, you could try `core, tucker_factors = tucker(X, rank=tucker_rank, n_iter_max=100, tol=10e-10, init='svd')`.

Comment: yes i need the factors and core to be non-negative.

Comment: Thank you ,its working just perfect.Thanks to tensorly Library.One more thing that you have mentioned add_noise() function in the article but i am not getting this function even i updated the tensorly.

Comment: add_noise is indeed missing, will add it